# How to make a timer in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a timer that starts when i create an instance of a class, and stop the timer when a method is called. Does anyone know how to make one? I've searched up many tutorials but got no idea what they're doing or it just doesn't fit my code. When i use `self.frame.destroy()` it needs to ignore the timer code so it doesn't get destroyed. The timer should include second and minutes (and milliseconds if possible). Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class Start:
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master = master
        #code

    def timer(self):
        #start timer
    
    def end(self):
        #end timer

root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**: The timer should start from 00:00:00 and not an updating clock.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-stopwatch-using-python/

It is actually a stopwatch program which includes hour, minute and second, it has three buttons *start*, *stop* and *reset* with their respective functions.

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged on this site.